# How can select data with column name contain bracket in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataTable in VB.net as:
[image]

I want select data by column `"概略質量(kg)"`

```
Dim arrDataCol = parm_dtDataHTMLFile.Select(String.Format("{0} is not null and {0} <> ''", "概略質量(kg)"))
```

Occur Error:

```
The expression contains undefined function call 概略質量().
```

How can select data with column name contain bracket in VB.Net?

Comment: Why would you be comparing data that obviously represents numbers to an empty string? Please tell me that you're not using a text column to store numbers. If you're not then a comparison of a number to a string makes no sense at all.

Comment: All Column is String Type.

Comment: Making the data type for a column text of some sort when the data is obviously numbers is very bad. What would an empty string even mean in this case? It's not null and it's not zero so what is it? You should ALWAYS use the most appropriate data type for the data you intend to store. If the data is numeric, use a numeric data type. If you have control of the database, you should fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces and other special characters in a column name require it to be wrapped in brackets. For the record, there's no brackets in your column name. They are parentheses.

```vb
Dim arrDataCol = parm_dtDataHTMLFile.Select("[概略質量(kg)] is not null and [概略質量(kg)] <> ''")
```

I'd suggest that you shouldn't be using column names like that in the first place. There's no requirement to use the same text for the column name and labels on the column in your app.